# How come array passed to constructor is not in sync with class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I thought you can access properties by reference instead of value, which is needed to stay in sync?

I have an element and i'm passing an array of Refs. When I console.log() the refs it's an empty array. But if I console.log() it inside Controller  I can see it's an array of refs.

So on each click (I see this output):

```
[] <-- empty array inside ControlsController.  
[{ current: ... }, {...}] <-- correct output inside Controller.
```

Why it's not in sync and how to get it to refer to same array?

```
class Controller extends React.Component<ControllerProps, ControllerState> {
  public state = {
    startIndex: 0,
    endIndex: 6,
    tempTestProp: ""
  };

  public itemRefs: Array<React.RefObject<HTMLLIElement | {}>> = [];

  public generateRefs = memoize((children) => {
    return Array.from({
      ......
    }).map((_, index) => React.createRef());
  });

  public controlsController = new ControlsController({
    element: this,
    list: this.listRef,
    items: this.itemRefs <------ here
  });

  public render() {
    ...........

     .........

    this.itemRefs = this.generateRefs(children);

    return render({
      ......
      itemRefs: this.itemRefs as Array<React.RefObject<HTMLLIElement>>,
      .......
    });
  }

  private handleControlClick = (direction: string) => (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>
  ) => {
    console.log(this.itemRefs) // [ {..}, {..} .. ]
    this.controlsController.move(event, direction);
  };
}
```

This is my ControlsController

```
class ControlsController {

  constructor({ ..., items, ... }: ConstructorProps) {
    .....
    this.items = items;
    ....
  }
public move( ... ) {
    switch (direction) {
      case "next":
        return moveNext.call(this);
    }
  }


function moveNext(this: ControlsControllerInterface) {
  console.log(this.items); // []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript arrays and objects are a reference in the Java sense of the word, not in the C/C++ sense of the word. Which means "reference" is short for "reference *value*", and it behaves like a pointer. So on this line:

```
this.itemRefs = this.generateRefs(children);
```

You're reassigning your `itemRefs` reference value / pointer with a different pointer, but `ControlsController` still has the same pointer to the original empty array.

Since this is react and you're dealing with state changes, seems like you should make itemRefs part of the state, then create your ControlsController inside render. That way react will automagically do the right thing when the state changes.

Comment: thanks - is the performance impact high if you instantiate ControlsController on each render? I'm planning to keep translate3d(state.X) in state, and pass it to a style={{ transform: `translate3d(0, state.X, 0)}`} later and want smooth swiping.

Comment: Depends on what ControlsController actually does in its constructor. But I'd wager that no, it won't be a high performance impact. On state changes, remember, react is already computing a new virtual dom and updating the real dom. I'm guessing your ControlsController will be a tiny blip in the scheme of things. But if you want, instead of re-instantiating ControlsController, you could just update it's reference. `render() { controlsController.items = this.state.itemRefs; ...`